# django - NoReverseMatch form

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem with my app.

```
#urls
url(r'generator/$', SelectView.as_view()),
    name="select"),
url(r'choices/(?P<types>\w+)$', ChoicesView.as_view()),
    name="choice"),

#views
class SelectView(FormView):
    template_name = "generator/show_choices.html"
    form_class = ChoiceForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        types = form.cleaned_data["type"]
        return redirect(reverse_lazy(
            "choice",
            kwargs={"types": types}))

#template
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'report_filtering' reporttype %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
```

And I get error: Reverse for 'choice' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'pl/generator/choice/(?P\w+)$'], when I open generator/ page.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to add more info. The reverse in your form does not even exists in your urls. Notwhithstanding that the urls have an extra ')' before the 'name' kwarg

Comment: Is that your complete template? Look for reverse or {% url %}.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it is attempting to use `choice` in the url, instead of `choices`, as you have it set to do in your `urls.py`.

Try correcting your syntax and see if it works:

```
url(r'^generator/$', SelectView.as_view(),
    name="select")),
url(r'^choices/(?P<types>\w+)/$', ChoicesView.as_view(),
    name="choice")),
```